# getting troubles installing Rust on Debian 12 via CURL

Tags: curl, rust, installation, debian-bookworm

I get trouble installing rust via "curl" on my Debian Bookwarm. I installed via apt build-essential, so i suppose everything should work fine but nothing i miss my rust installation.
``

I launch this command copied and pasted on my terminal:

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`

After some minute I got this response:

`curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 300045 milliseconds`

So i tried via terminal this command:
`ping static.rust-lang.org`

No response got after some minutes, so i stopped the process.
What' wrong?

Comment: If you are unable to access static.rust-lang.org then you're probably going to have a bad time. You should investigate if something (firewall, router, isp, etc.) is blocking it.

Comment: Try other hosts: `example.com` or `stackoverflow.com`. It sounds like you have a crippling DNS failure. Check your DNS settings. Check that you can `ping 1.1.1.1` or something well-known and likely to be alive.

Comment: I'am in a public library in Italy, may be you are right. Tomorrow or after tomorrow I try with another connection. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i'am alive ping 8.8.8.8 responds. But i don't know how to check my DNS.

Comment: If it was a DNS failure, `ping` would exit immediately with `ping: static.rust-lang.org: Name or service not known`. However it can be a firewall or router issue. Especially if you're connecting from a public network.

Comment: thanks a lot. You confirm my suspicious!